# How can access textfield ids with page id in JQM

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I have same id in two different pages in JQM.

Question:

How can I able to access these id with page ids
as we know that in JQM every page has its own id:

```
$('#pageId #textfieldId').val();
```

Or some thing different?

Comment: This should work or `$.mobile.activePage.find('textarea').val();`

Comment: @Irfan Please stop trying to correct people's grammar in suggested edits. You keep replacing correct grammar with incorrect grammar. "How can I able to" and ["Can not able to"](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4478116) aren't just a little off, they're ***glaringly*** incorrect English, and in both cases the grammar was correct before you changed it. It's not just these two instances, I've noticed you do this sort of thing in the past. Please leave grammar corrections to those who have a reliable sense of English grammar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below code to get value of a text area in the active page.

```
$.mobile.activePage.find('textarea').val();
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

```
$('#pageId #textfieldId').val();
```

Use:

```
$('.pageId .textfieldId').val();
```

You can only trigger unique ID's

Comment: if i have two pages with ids profile and tool and a text field in both pages with same id then how can i access these ids because if i directly then there will be possibility of misunderstanding due to cache technique in JQM

Comment: Then I think you need to go for Omar's comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#pageId').find('textfieldId').val();
```